# Build Dockerfile without docker on Kubernetes (AKS 1.19.0) running with containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, containerd

I have Azure devops pipeline, building dockerfile on AKS, as AKS is deprecating docker with the latest release, kindly suggest best practice to have a dockerfile build without docker on AKS cluster.
Exploring on Kaniko, buildah to build without docker..

Comment: kaniko would work, i think tekton can also do that

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has changed.  You can still use `docker build` and `docker push` on your developer or CI system to build and push the Docker image to a repository.  The only difference is that using Docker proper as the container backend within your Kubernetes cluster isn't a supported option any more, but this is a low-level administrator-level decision that your application doesn't know or care about.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you were somehow building using the host docker socket within your Kubernetes cluster, this change will not affect you. And if you were mounting the docker socket from the host in a kubernetes cluster, I'd consider that a security concern that you want to fix.

Docker Desktop runs a docker engine as a container on top of containerd, allowing developers to build and run containers in that environment. Similar can be done with DinD build patterns that run the docker engine inside a container, the difference is the underlying container management tooling is containerd instead of a full docker engine, but the containerized docker engine is indifferent to that.

As an alternative to building within the full docker engine, I'd recommend looking at [buildkit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit) which is the current default build tool in docker as of 20.10. It uses containerd and they ship a [selection of manifests](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/tree/master/examples/kubernetes) to run builds directly in kubernetes as a standalone builder.